# Filter results from Elasticsearch if only a specific field matches

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the following query for searching across multiple fields:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "italian sports car",
      "fields": ["car_name", "car_brand", "car_description", "car_country"],
      "type": "most_fields"
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, I'm looking for sports cars made in Italy (hence the `car_country` field). However, this will return all the cars made in Italy even if they are not sports cars. I want `car_country` to be just an auxiliary search field, so I don't want hits when the only matched field is `car_country`. Is this possible? I know I can set a lower score for that field, but I want hits with only this matching field to be completely ignored.

Comment: Can you update your question with mappings? It will be easier to debug the problem by writing a new query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be different ways you handle this problem depending on the scoring etc. you require from you results. For instance -

Use a bool query with 2 parts

1. Must query - include queries that must match for the document to be in the resultset
2. Should query - include queries that should match(and impact scoring) but do not decide if a document should or should not be in the result set.

Add the multi-match query without the car_country field in must query and a match query for car_country field in should query.

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "italian sports car",
                        "fields": [
                            "car_name",
                            "car_brand",
                            "car_description"
                        ],
                        "type": "most_fields"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "car_country": {
                            "query": "italian sports car"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this can work! Actually, I had to change the syntax of the `match` query using Elasticsearch 7.11 (remove `field` and use it as a top-level attribute inside `match`) and boost it a little bit, but it's working as expected. Thanks!